# What exceptions can a plain 'where' query cause using LINQ to Entities in EF 6.1?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I know it's a tough question, but maybe there is a list somewhere maybe? This is assuming the predicate doesn't cause an error or a type conversion when materialising an object, that type of thing.

I mean more operational exceptions, like a bad connection or timeout or something.

Comment: I accidentally chose the wrong bounty reason. I just want more attention for the question, i.e. more answers.

Comment: I don't think such comprehensive list exists. Could you shed some light on what would be a broader context?

Comment: I don't want to catch Exception from an EF query, but I don't know what narrower exception(s) to catch, and I do want a try-catch around all operations that venture outside the control of my code only.

Comment: Assuming that the list could contain possibly dozens of different exceptions, wrapping an invocation in a detailed list of all possible exceptions sound like a tedious task. I would definitely catch a general exception instead.

Comment: @WiktorZychla It seems it is the case that the list is too long. What I will do is use semantic logging to build a list of common, more derived exceptions during production use, and eventually, when the growth of that list slows enough, implement catches for the list of types.

Comment: That sounds reasonable.

Comment: My question is what you do if you catch the exceptions? Do you know how to handle them all (unlikely)? Or you just need to log something and re-throw (in which case catch all may be a actually a good idea)? Also if you have a Linq query you can get an exception when the query is evaluated so the answer to your question is 'where' by itself does not throw (e.g. this `ctx.Categories.Where(c => ((string)null).Length > 0)` until you enforce evaluation by calling `.ToList()`, `.First()` etc.

Comment: Since EF is open source, you could try looking at that. Might not be too easy, though. http://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest

Comment: @Pawel I did say during object materialization, which happens after the query has executed and returned results.

Comment: @Steve, that was my first idea of a solution, but it would involve way too much work, and we'd be running on a compromised EF fork for a worldwide security system.

Comment: There are 8901 items in my SQL database in English in sys.messages alone.  I tried looking in there for stuff related to 'connections' and it was....  Not helpful.  Assuming sometimes EF passes back the full SQL error and uses that message_id, you could be looking at a fundamentally useless dataset.  Why do you need special cases?  Wouldn't it make sense to have a generalized try...catch and then define special situations for individual errors you care about specifically?

Comment: I have to ensure a try-catch-log-throw structure for all data access. As one always should, I at least tried to find a way of catching more specific errors. What if something else throws a different `Exception` and I must do more handling?

Comment: I think this is the case for pretty much everything. It's always possible an exception occurs that's unexpected. That's their nature.